# What is the order of a cusp form at a cusp?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, modular-forms

This question is about the definition of order of a section of a bundle at a point, and the related notion of associated divisor.

Let us look at a specific example, the discriminant $\Delta(z)$ on $X(1) = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$. If $q$ is a local parameter at the cusp $i\infty$ then
$$ \Delta(q) = q + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n q^n,$$
and one would be tempted to deduce

> $$\mathrm{ord}_{\,i\infty}(\Delta) = 1.$$

On the other hand one could read the excellent answer of Georges Elencwajg to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031510/divisor-of-meromorphic-section-of-point-bundle-over-a-riemann-surface) question. If $U$ is a small neighborhood around $i\infty$, and we denote by $\mathcal{S}_K$ the bundle of cusp forms of weight $k$ and by $\mathcal{M}_k$ the bundle of modular forms of weight $k$, then
$$\mathrm{H}^0(U,\mathcal{S}_k) \simeq \mathrm{H}^0(U,\mathcal{O}_X)\qquad \text{via } f(q) \mapsto f(q)/q,$$
but
$$\mathrm{H}^0(U,\mathcal{M}_k) \simeq \mathrm{H}^0(U,\mathcal{O}_X)\qquad \text{via } g(q) \mapsto g(q).$$
Thus I would now say that

> $$ \mathrm{ord}_{\,i\infty}(\Delta) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{
> assuming } \Delta \in \mathrm{H}^0(X(1),\mathcal{S}_{12}),\\ 1 &
> \text{ assuming } \Delta \in \mathrm{H}^0(X(1),\mathcal{M}_{12}),\\
> \end{cases} $$

Consequently, **I wouldn't have a notion of $\mathrm{div}(\Delta)$ if I don't fix the bundle of whom $\Delta$ is a section.**

This looks quite weird to me, and the experts I asked to just told me: "look at the $q$-expansion, since it starts with $q$ it has order $1$".

Summing up:

1. Is it true that $\mathrm{ord}_{\,i\infty}(\Delta)$ is 0, resp. 1, if I look at it as a section of $\mathcal{S}_{12}$, resp. $\mathcal{M}_{12}$?
2. Does it imply that I don't have a "universal" notion of divisor of a section of a bundle, as long as I don't specify of which bundle it is a section?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you are correct on both (1) and (2). I guess the "experts" you consulted are very accustomed to the fact that the definition of the bundle of modular forms is chosen such that you can read off the order of vanishing at $\infty$ from the $q$-expansion.

Comment: Thanks! I've been a bit confused by the general sloppiness that seems to permeate this issue...

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Hi, I really need you for your knowledge on modular forms, tks ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325266/hecke-operators-acting-on-the-jacobian-jx-1n?noredirect=1#comment4789420_2325266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by David Loeffler in the comments both points $(1)$ and $(2)$ are correct.