# Hecke operators acting on the Jacobian $J(X_1(N))$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

I'm stuck with [p.238](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf) of Diamond's book on modular forms. If $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^g$ is the eigenform basis of $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$, fixing $p_0 \in X_0(N)$ we have an holomorphic map $$\phi : X_0(N) \to J(X_0(N)) = \mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda, \qquad \phi(p) = \left(\int_{p_0}^p f_1(z)dz, \ldots, \int_{p_0}^p f_1(z)dz\right)$$
where $\Lambda \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ is the image of the closed loops in $X_0(N)$.

**Question :** can you explain how the Hecke operators $ \langle d \rangle,T_n: S_k(\Gamma_0(N)) \to S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ act on the Jacobian variety $J(X_0(N))$ ?

---

Edit : [Milne p.150](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Milne%20J.S.%20Elliptic%20curves%20and%20algebraic%20geometry.%20Math679%20U%20Michigan%20notes%20(draft%201996)(163s).pdf) explains it much better, in such a way that it is obvious $T_p \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda$, and assuming they are equal, we get an action of $T_p on $J(X_0(N))$

Comment: the explanation is the content of the following few pages.

Comment: doesn't it act on the zeros in exactly the same way as it acts on the poles .... ?

Comment: [Milne p.150](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Milne%20J.S.%20Elliptic%20curves%20and%20algebraic%20geometry.%20Math679%20U%20Michigan%20notes%20(draft%201996)(163s).pdf) explains it much better