# An estimate of the second moment of the Ramanujan $\tau$- function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $\tau$ the Ramanujan $\tau$-function, it is proved [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-040-01/S0002-9939-1973-0327682-0/S0002-9939-1973-0327682-0.pdf) that 
$$\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^\theta}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\log p\gg x^\theta\quad (1)$$ 
for some $\theta<1.$ My question is: how we can infer from that result the following
$$\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^\theta}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\gg x^{\theta}\quad (2)$$

Comment: It's a different (smaller) value of $\theta$ in the second equation.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, Thanks, could you give me the method to infer it?

Comment: ? $\log x \leq \log p \leq \log(x + x^{\theta}) \ll \log x$...

Comment: Come on it is trivial. $$\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^\theta}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\log p\gg x^\theta \implies \sum_{x\le p\le x+x^\theta}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\gg \frac{x^\theta}{\log x} \gg x^{\theta-\epsilon}$$

Comment: @PeterHumphries I'm stuck with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325266/hecke-operators-acting-on-the-jacobian-jx-1n) could you please tell me what to work on ?

Comment: Did you prove the prime number theorem (for $\zeta(s)$) ?

Comment: Come on... As we wrote it is trivial. Once you have (2) for some $\theta'$ then (1) follows with the same $\theta'$. Did you prove the prime number theorem before reading those kind of generalization for modular forms ?

Comment: @user1952009, Yes, I have read it but not in details!! Okay if we prove that : $$\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^\theta}\tau(p)p^{-11}\gg x^{\theta'}$$ how we can get $$\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^{\theta'}}\tau(p)p^{-11}\gg x^{\theta'}$$?

Comment: This is probably a typo he meant $\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^{\theta}}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\log p\gg x^{\theta}$

Comment: @user1952009, i don't think so!!

Comment: In the cited paper this is what he shows.. And I don't think he uses $\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^{\theta}}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\gg x^{\theta}$ specifically

Comment: @user1952009, Do you have any idea how to prove (ii)lemma 4?

Comment: Why would you need it ? And I'd say $\sum_{x\le p\le x+x^{\theta}}\tau(p)^2p^{-11}\gg x^{\theta}$ is not true since it would contradict the prime number theorem for $\sum_{p < x} \tau(p)^2 p^{-11}$

Comment: @user1952009, I think that I will post the question in MO.

Comment: @user1952009, My objective is to prove (ii) lemma 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-040-01/S0002-9939-1973-0327682-0/S0002-9939-1973-0327682-0.pdf) explains p.3 $$\sum_{p < x} \tau(p)^2 p^{-11} \log p \sim x,\qquad \sum_{p < x} \tau(p)^2 p^{-11}  \sim \frac{x}{\log x} $$ is the prime number theorem for this L-function

thus
$\sum_{p \in [x,x+x^\theta]} \tau(p)^2 p^{-11}\gg x^\theta$ can't be true, since it would imply
$$\sum_{p < x}\tau(p)^2 p^{-11} \gg \int_2^x \frac{ \sum_{p \in [y,y+y^\theta]} \tau(p)^2 p^{-11}}{y^\theta} dy \gg x$$

Comment: hahahah then Lemma 4 from Murty's paper is false?

Comment: @square-free if you want to continue the discussion, explain what you did and what you want to do